# Java Generic Factory pattern implementation

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, factory

What I am trying to do, is implementig a clickstream data generator, that can be extended in a nice way.

What I was thinking of:

The properties are Classes, e.g. each user has some kind of browser. So there is a browser class. Same for language, plugins etc....

For each Property there is a Factory that creates me a random instance of a Property e.g. new Browser("Firefox") or new Language("German"). The possible values are stored in a file for each property.

Basically all these factories and property classes are doing the same thing. Right now i have a seperate factory for each property and for each new porperty i have to generate a new factory.

My Question is, is there a possibility to implement some kind of generic factory for all the properties i have, and for new ones to come.

This is my code:

```
public abstract class Property {

protected String value;
Random rand;

public Property(String value) {
    this.rand = new Random();
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {      
    return this.value;
}
}


public class Browser extends Property{

public Browser(String value) {
    super(value);
}
}

public abstract class AbstractFactory implements IFactory{
List<String> valuesList;
FileReader fileReader;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;
Random rand;

public AbstractFactory(String inputFile) {      
    rand = new Random();
    this.valuesList = new LinkedList<String>();     
    String line = null;

    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            valuesList.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}


import model.Browser;

public class BrowserFactory extends AbstractFactory{

public BrowserFactory(String inputFile) {
    super(inputFile);
}

@Override
public Browser getInstance() {      
    return new Browser(valuesList.get(rand.nextInt(valuesList.size())));
}

}
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: What you want is surely possible, but I need some more information to figure out what you need.  Are you sure that something like the Builder pattern might not suit you better?

Comment: What i want, ist top get rid of all the factory classes i have (one for each Feature) that all do the same Thing. The only difference between Thema is a different Input path and a different Output Type of the getinstance method.

Comment: I want something Like this in my Main method: FeatureFactory f1 = new FeatureFactory<Browser>("Input/path");
FeatureFactory f2 = new FeatureFactory<Language>("Input/path2");

Answer (score 1):

Hungarian notation (technically, systems Hungarian notation) is frowned upon.  Java interfaces should not be named with an `I` prefix.  If you look at the [Java SE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) you will see that there is not a single interface named that way.

So, with that in mind, you would define `Factory` as:

```
public interface Factory<T> {
    T getInstance();
}
```

Then AbstractFactory copies that:

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory<T> implements Factory<T> {
```

Finally, BrowserFactory can simply make the generic type more specific:

```
public class BrowserFactory extends AbstractFactory<Browser> {
    @Override
    public Browser getInstance() {
```

If you want to make a single concrete class, you’ll need some uniform way of creating the classes.  If they all have constructors which take a String, you can use reflection:

```
public class FeatureFactory<T> extends AbstractFactory<T> {
    private final Constructor<T> constructor;

    public FeatureFactory(Class<T> featureType) {
        try {
            this.constructor = featureType.getConstructor(String.class);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Cannot find/access (String) constructor in " + featureType, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T getInstance() {
        try {
            return constructor.newInstance(
                valuesList.get(rand.nextInt(valuesList.size())));
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You must pass a Class object for reflection to work.  Generics are erased at runtime, so you cannot derive the class from just `<T>`.  In fact, you’ll find that Java SE classes work the same way;  see [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) for examples.

Another somewhat cleaner approach is using a Java 8 [Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html):

```
public class FeatureFactory<T> extends AbstractFactory<T> {
    private final Function<String, ? extends T> creator;

    public FeatureFactory(Function<String, ? extends T> creator) {
        this.creator = Objects.requireNonNull(creator,
            "Creation function cannot be null");
    }

    @Override
    public T getInstance() {
        creator.apply(
            valuesList.get(rand.nextInt(valuesList.size())));
    }
}
```

This could be invoked with something like:

```
FeatureFactory<Browser> browserFactory = new FeatureFactory<>(Browser::new);
```